# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "чем"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, сравнительный-оборот

Ему нужно больше, чем остальным.

Answer (score 2):

Оборот, присоединяемый союзом **чем**, выделяется (или отделяется) запятыми, если в предложении называются или подразумеваются **два сравниваемых понятия.**

*Шут необходим толпе **более, чем** герой* (М. Горький. Жизнь Клима Самгина). *Милый зверь накуролесил на новом месте **еще больше, чем** у меня* (Д. Мамин-Сибиряк. Мeдведко).
[(НЕ) БОЛЕЕ / БОЛЬШЕ, ЧЕМ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_68)

Перед союзом **чем** запятая необходима.

**Ему нужно больше, чем** [нужно] **остальным.**
*Он уже старик, ему нужно отдыхать больше, чем другим парням* (из статьи).
*Им нужно больше, чем просто деньги* ("Огонёк", 2010).

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна:

> ***Обособляется*** сравнительный оборот, присоединяющийся союзами словно, будто, как будто, точно, **чем**, нежели, что и др, если не входит в
>   состав сказуемого

http://school-collection.edu.ru/dlrstore-wrapper/1946d260-e1a1-4308-8126-72b39aaea09a/punc17.htm